# My application won't terminate

Tags: vb.net, winforms

VB.NET program.

While developing on Visual Studio Express 2010, there are two buttons: Start Debugging, and Stop Debugging.

Well, while debugging, I close my application (the red X button). However, when I look back at Visual Studio, it seems to still be in debugging mode (the Start button is disabled, and the Stop button is enabled). So I have to manually press the Stop button.

I remember it was not like this before.

Perhaps it is because my application uses multiple forms or something? Then I am probably missing something rather important... Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got something open somewhere. You can force the entire app to quit by adding

```
End
```

in the form's FormClosed event:

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    End
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing any threading?  Shutting down your primary app leaving threads running will cause what you are seeing.   Also app design can cause what you are seeing.  You can start your vb.net app running a "main" procedure, but if you don't provide an exit for it, the app will continue to run.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that all hidden forms (if any) are closed, properly dispose all objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hiding any form and forgot to close it in your application this scenario may happen. Or if you are using threading in your application and they are not terminating properly then also it happens.